# POST csv contents to HTTP API C#

Tags: c#, api, http, post

Once again, I am new to C# and I am forcing myself through some exercises and putting the theory into practice. I am currently working on a small app to post the contents of a large csv file (2000+ lines) to a http API. The API is in the format

```
https://mydomain.com//api/dump/?
             t = <app_token> // provided by auth function
             &[
                xml = <device_data_package> 
                OR
                csv = <device_data_package>
```

My question is, how would i pass the csv contents to the body of the http POST? I appreciate your feedback and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like other answers have said, assuming you have the code to open your file and read the contents, your CSV file will contain a string with values separated by commas. You can add it as a url parameter to give you something like this:

https://mydomain.com//api/dump/?t=my_token&csv=my,values,from,my,csv,file,go,here

However, there are limitations to the length of urls. So if you have anything other than a small CSV file, you are better off sending the CSV data as the body of the post, like you mention in your question.

The method below might come in handy. It takes an object as a parameter and embeds it into a post request and returns the response as a string. I have been using it on a site of mine to send data to an external service. It is part of a much bigger class, so I might have too many using statements.

You would use it like this:

```
WebUtilities.Post("https://mydomain.com//api/dump/?t=my_token", "csv=" + contents_of_my_csv_file);
```

The method looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Xml;

public static class WebUtilities
{
    public static string Post(string url, object postData)
    {
        HttpWebRequest httpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        bf.Serialize(ms, postData);

        byte[] data = ms.ToArray();

        httpWReq.Method = "POST";
        httpWReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        httpWReq.ContentLength = data.Length;

        using (Stream newStream = httpWReq.GetRequestStream())
        {
            newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();

        Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();

        Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");

        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream, encode);

        string html = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

        response.Close();

        streamReader.Close();

        return html;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thank you, I will give this a try and get back to you Keith.

Comment: So the CSV file has 2000+ lines so the only way would be to load the whole file in the post body. Help Please?

Comment: Yes, the method above should do that for you. Open the file and pass the contents as a parameter to the method as described above.

Comment: Ok, getting a 400 bad request so i would assume that I need to escape the url? '  WebPortalAPI.Post("https://mydomain.com/api/dump/?t=" + appToken + "", "csv=" + content);'

Comment: Thank you for your help. I can now properly post.

Answer (score 0):

The API should provide some specifications, but usually it'll just be one giant comma separated string like the following:

```
string foo = "bar1, bar2, bar3, soomanybars, notabar";
```